# How to get deleted workitems using RTC Java API

Tags: java, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I want to get list of workitems that are deleted from a project.

How might I accomplish this using the RTC Java API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting is one this, as this [thread suggests](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/140860/how-to-delete-workitem-programmatically):

```
    IWorkItem workItem = workItemClient.findWorkItemById(id, IWorkItem.SMALL_PROFILE, monitor);
    IDetailedStatus status = workItemClient.deleteWorkItem(workItem, monitor);
    
    if (!status.isOK()) {
            throw new TeamRepositoryException("Error deleting work item",
                    status.getException());
    }

    System.out.println("Deleted work item: " + idString + ".");
```

But *listing* the work items deleted is, I don't know if there is a Java API which access to the delete_items table.
See [comment 11](https://jazz.net/jazz/resource/itemOid/com.ibm.team.workitem.WorkItem/_wqo_EPECEd-W3Nt5qijYpg?path=internalComments%5B11%5D) of Task 140053:

> There is a record in `deleted_items` table about all items that are deleted along with the timestamp of when they were deleted.

[Task 149432](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=149432) mentions:

> Surface a delete work item action in the Eclipse UI

So there is a visible record. [Enhancement 151766](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=149432&tab=com.ibm.team.workitem.tab.links) mentions that "Java ETL should handle deleted Work Items", so there might be an API as well.

Note that it would only get your the ID of the deleted work item and the date of the deletion, not the work item itself.
As mentioned [in this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/203845/can-deleted-work-items-still-be-viewed):

> When you delete a work item, it will be lost permanently.
>
> Sometimes, people create a kind of "Trash Can Project Area", so deleted work items are moved to, instead to be really deleted.

---

As the [OP Neha S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3458569/neha-s) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224051/how-to-get-deleted-workitems-using-rtc-java-api/32224139#comment52334337_32224139), if the following code returns `NULL`, it can indicate a deletion:

```
IWorkItem workItem = workItemClient.findWorkItemById(id, IWorkItem.FULL_PROFILE, monitor);
```

Comment: This deletes work items, he wants to list the ones that are already deleted

Comment: Suppose a particular workItem is deleted then what will I get for below statement:      `IWorkItem workItem = workItemClient.findWorkItemById(id, IWorkItem.FULL_PROFILE, monitor);`?

Comment: @Neha: You won't get anything. A deleted work items leaves only its id and date of deletion behind. Nothing else.

Comment: @NehaS yes, the full work item object is no longer available.

Comment: Then that will help me to identify whether its deleted. Thanks a lot VonC